# Reloading RecyclerView doesn’t update items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am using the following code:

```
refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

The activity contains a recycler view, I want the activity to reload when I click on refresh but the Recyclerview doesn't fill again, it has the same information than before reloading. If I go to another activity and come back to this one, then it does change.
What I am doing wrong?

Here is the complete activity code:

```
public class SyncActivity extends Activity {

    private static String TAG = "SynActivity";

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private TextView textView;
    private ImageView backArrow;
    private ImageView refresh;

    // Sesión actual
    private Usuario usuario;
    private String sessionid;

    List<TrafficSign> tsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sync);

        tsList = new ArrayList<TrafficSign>();

        // Sesión actual
        sessionid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sessionid");
        usuario = (Usuario) getIntent().getExtras().get("usuario");

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto);
        backArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backarrow);
        refresh = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.refresh);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // specify an adapter with the list to show
        ConexionSQLiteHelper conexionSQLiteHelper = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this, NOMBRE_BD, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase dbread = conexionSQLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = dbread.rawQuery(COMRPUEBA_SYNC, new String[]{usuario.getUsername()});

        // Si hay conexión a internet y hay datos en SQLite, sincronizamos.
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
                    tsList.add(new TrafficSign(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(CAMPO_LONGITUD)),
                            c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(CAMPO_LATITUD)),
                            c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(CAMPO_ANCHO)),
                            c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(CAMPO_ALTO)),
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CAMPO_CLASE)),
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CAMPO_USERNAME))));
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
            }
            c.close();
            dbread.close();
            mAdapter = new SyncAdapter(tsList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }else{
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SyncActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("sessionid", sessionid);
                intent.putExtra("usuario", usuario);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that fills your RecyclerView? Also, is there a separate reason you want to refresh the activity itself, or is it just the RecyclerView's content you're interested in? If that's the case, [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()) should do the trick.

Comment: @LukeSykpe notifyDataSetChange() doesn't work in my case, because the dataset won't change if the activity doesn't reload. The thing is I get information from SQLite when there is no internet and I display it on the recycler view. When I activate the internet again the SQLite data erased and it should be nothing on the RecyclerView, but for that we have to reaload the Activity and query the SQLite db again.

Comment: @LukeSykpe I edit the question to let you see the activity code in case you need it.

Comment: What's stopping you from running the SQLite query code inside your `onClick()`, rather than refreshing the Activity? I don't really see anything wrong with your code - unless I'm missing something, it should work. Are you sure the SQLite data is actually changing?

Comment: @LukeSykpe Yes, it's changing, because if I go to another activity and then comeback it changes. I will try running the SQLite query code inside onClick(). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can Simply use

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

to refresh an `Activity` from within itself.